# html5 svg is not showing

Tags: html, svg

I'm new to html5 svg rendering. I tried this :

```
<svg width="200" height="200"> 
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 64 64" id="shape-phone">
        <title>phone</title> 
        <g> 
            <rect x="16" y="1" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="32" height="62"/> 
            <line fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="28" y1="5" x2="36" y2="5"/> 
            <line fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="16" y1="51" x2="48" y2="51"/> 
            <line fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="16" y1="9" x2="48" y2="9"/> 
            <circle fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="32" cy="57" r="2"/> 
        </g> 
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

But this doesn't work. Any idea, how to modify above to get it work?

**Update :**

Trying to show the svg symbol using `use` also doesn't work.

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#shape-phone" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a `<symbol>` but you need to display it with a `<use>`:

```
<use xlink:href="#shape-phone" x="0" y="0" width="64" height="64" />
```

Symbols are a kind of template, made to be reused over and over again. The `<symbol>` tag defines the graphical content which can be shown with one ore more `<use>` elements. Each `<use>` can be transformed in any way, but you cannot set different styles for their content, since the content is more a link to the one from the symbol, so it does not have a »real« own DOM which can be styled.

**UPDATE**

It may happen that you need to include the `xlink` namespace in the `<svg>` like so:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" …>…</svg>
```

the Symbol is not showing up, because there is no `stroke` set.

```
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 64 64" id="shape-phone">
    <g> 
        <rect x="16" y="1" stroke="#00ff00" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="32" height="62"/> 
        <line fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="28" y1="5" x2="36" y2="5"/> 
        <line fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="16" y1="51" x2="48" y2="51"/> 
        <line fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="16" y1="9" x2="48" y2="9"/> 
        <circle fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="32" cy="57" r="2"/> 
    </g> 
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#shape-phone" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol